# How does ArrayFormula work?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to understand when does `ARRAYFORMULA` decide to expand a range, and when does it decide to repeat it.

According to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199028/google-sheets-arrayformula-and-ranges-rules) question:

> The rules for `ARRAYFORMULA` are:
>
> - If a function parameter inside `ARRAYFORMULA` is expected to be a scalar (criterion in the examle) and a range is given it will expand in the cells below iterating this range.
> - If a function parameter inside `ARRAYFORMULA` is expected to be a range (range and sumrange) and a range is given it will pass on the range    to the formula.

I wonder if it really is the case.

As an example, this is our table:

| Name | Count | Lookup | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 3 | John | 5 |
| Bob | 2 | Marta | 1 |
| Frank | 4 |  |  |
| John | 5 |  |  |
| Marta | 1 |  |  |

The Result column contains the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(FILTER(C2:C, LEN(C2:C)), A2:B, 2, FALSE))
```

For every name in column `C`, it searches the name in column `A` and returns the count.

Somehow, `ArrayFormula` knows that the vlookup should happen for every cell in `C2:C`, but that the argument `A2:B` should stay intact (to search in the whole table).

Why doesn't `ArrayFormula` expand the lookup range too, and searches `C2` in `A2:B2`, `C3` in `A3:B3` etc (which means it wouldn't find anything)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. When asking questions about Google Sheets formulas, please describe the spreadsheet structure and relevant settings i.e. the country as it affects the function parameter separator among other stuff, the timezone as it might affect import/export, and interactions with other apps like Google Apps Script. Include sample input data and the corresponding expected output, directly in the question body as text, include links to questions that you have found on this site, and a brief explanation about why they don't meet your needs.

Comment: When using open references include the size of the corresponding sheets. P.S. There is a work in progress to have [Guides to ask a \[google-sheets\] question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4935/88163) . At this time might not be good as a first stop. If you have time, please take a look at it and provide feedback.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks! I have actually read it and upvoted long before I've asked the question :-) I'm trying to explain a bit better, but my question is very generic regarding ARRAYFORMULA expansion rules. Working on editing it. Might have figured it out, but the question is still worth asking I believe.

Comment: @Rubén I hope the question is better now. Appreciate the kind explanations :-)

Comment: IMHO it's not a good idea to use rhetoric questions or other forms of "complex" statements having question marks as our site has all kinds of members. Some take question content overly literarily. Whenever possible use only one simple and direct statement including a question mark. One of the risks of having multiple statements with a question mark is that it might make the question closed as need more focus. Anyway, the question needs more focus because it looks to require a lengthy answer. Please narrow the scope of this question.

Comment: You might ask first a question about using ARRAYFORMULA with scalar functions (functions that return a single value), later a question with array formulas like FILTER (functions that return an array without the need of using ARRAYFORMULA), and later a question about using ARRAYFORMULA with custom functions.

Comment: @Rubén I was afraid of spamming with 3 different questions about different aspects of the same topic. Don't you believe that a single comprehensive answer to the working of the `ARRAYFORMULA` function is a good idea? I've searched a few hours on the web and found nothing, so I believe a detailed answer can be of great value. I actually thought of analyzing the OpenOffice code for that in order to understand it better, but I fear I went down the rabbit hole.

Comment: No, as it will require a lengthy answer. The best is to ask one question and wait to get at least one good answer, then "rinse and repeat" (ask a new question, and wait at least to get one good answer). On your 2nd and following questions mention the previous questions if they are directly related, if the new question is very similar to any previous question, yours or from others, clearly explain why it's being asked the second question (why it's "not a duplicate"). A common reason is to avoid having a question requiring a lengthy answer, another reason is to make follow-up questions.

Comment: Detailed answers are good while they aren't lenthy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145686/discussion-between-ruben-and-bharel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer your question by modifying/clarifying the explanation given in the previous answer to more closely match your example. The 'rules' of ARRAYFORMULA are:

- If a function parameter inside ARRAYFORMULA is expected to be a scalar  (VLOOKUP's *search_key* or *index* arguments in the example) and an array or range is supplied, an array output will be given whose dimensions match those of the input.
- Any function parameters inside ARRAYFORMULA which require an array or range by default (VLOOKUP's *range* in the example) are not changed.

So what you state at the end of your question ('*Somehow, ArrayFormula knows that the vlookup should happen for every cell in C2:C, but that the argument A2:B should stay intact*') is entirely correct given the above.

In the specific case of ARRAYFORMULA I find Google's documentation to be very poor, and a lot is left to the end-user to work out for themself.

Comment: So basically the function will be repeated for every scalar value combination (in case of multiple scalars) until the dimensions match the matrix of the scalar values?

Comment: I don't have a CompSci background so some of the terminology is right on the edge of my understanding, but I think this is correct. To go back to your example, if your VLOOKUP range was three columns rather than two, you could return the values in both the second and third columns corresponding to search_key C2:C by passing {2,3} to index (as C2:C is a column vector and {2,3} is a row vector so their dimensions are compatible)